# CSV list of all universities - google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3, maps

I have a CSV list of university names around the world - about 13,000 university names. I'm looking for a way to pull the addresses of these universities. Google Maps API / Google Places API looks promising, but requires lat/long to map the locations.

End game is to mark to each school as a 1 if the school is in the US, and 0 if the school is outside of the US.

Any thoughts on how to search these colleges in maps and pull out the addresses - or at least the country?

Example:

Answer (score 0):

is there nothing else in the csv, only the names?  that's going to make it hard, i'd bet the names aren't always unique in the world.

you could write something that had different passes at biting the apple - for instance, if the university has a state name in it, check those off as 1's - then find another logic to use to take "another bit" until the apple is gone.

Answer (score 0):

On top of @WEBjuju's answer, since you only want to mark if the school is in US, or outside of US, you can use the "country" type in Place Types in the Google Places API, by setting the option as country='us'.
https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types?csw=1#table2

You may also want to cross check with this list of schools.
https://www.4icu.org/reviews/index2.htm
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_universities_and_colleges_by_country